# Emacs dot files & packages List for user switching from sublime and not founding a starter kit tailored for them

Tags: package, customize

I'm trying to be able to answer to "sublime users" using a curated list of package, if not a working emacs config (like prelude or starter-kit does), but couldn't find any list or dotfiles for that on the web.
So looking around and from my packages and my very limited knowledge of sublime (from user questions), I gathered

- emacs built-ins: show-paren, save-desktop, frame-restore, package, theme
- projectile (projects...)
- sr-speedbar (for inside window project tree)
- project-persist (save the project, switch project, save windows)
- ido-flx ( C-M-o to projectile-find-file with ido-flx for "anything")
- anything-project
- smex
- recentf
- company (auto-complete)
- flycheck and its linters
- multi-occur (search in open buffers)
- iedit ("mutiple cursor")

As I guess many other emacs user had that question, and answered, I'm looking for what I missed and can use/suggest to sublime user looking for switching ?

The question is: **If I'm to build a "sublime-starter-kit" emacs distribution like "prelude"** , what packages and features would I need other than those listed ?

Comment: You have better chances getting good answers if you ask about an individual, specific feature that you are looking for in Emacs.

Comment: Problem is I'm asking about any sublime feature I might have missed but don't know about.(emacs user here, not knowing sublime enough)

Comment: The question and answer can also be a starter point "search answer" for sublime users looking for a list when switching. Need a single post rather than "feature by feature" search. Question is broad by definition. But as "Sublime" text editor is the current hotness, seems to me many people already had to answer "switchers" and may already have a tailored list, which means a correct single small answer is possible.

Answer (score 3):

My [series of guides](http://tuhdo.github.io/) contain a lot of demos for cool features in Emacs.

You may want to look at my [mini manual](http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-tutor.html), look at my [Helm guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) and [Helm Projectile guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) for many demos.

An example: You can move between Semantic units of your programming language with `helm-semantic-or-imenu`. [Demo](http://tuhdo.github.io/static/part3/helm-semantic-or-imenu-2.gif).

[Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) is a nice example of dot files and starter kit.